# New, duplicate answer posted for 5-month old question

Tags: support, specific-answer

This is an answer posted by a new user for a 5-month old question:

[Find the missing number in the series: 253, 495, 143,?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24513/find-the-missing-number-in-the-series-253-495-143/32144#32144)

I see multiple issues with it:

- It's not formatted properly
- Almost an exact duplicate of the answer above it, but probably not copied, just answered innocently by the new user
- Repeats info already in the question

I'm kind of confused how we can handle this. Should I custom flag it as a duplicate, or request to delete altogether?

- I don't think the answer is VLQ as it could be improved through editing.
- I would also like to encourage the user to check existing answers before posting, and upvote instead of posting a duplicate answer.

Comment: Also, about the question, I think we should ask the asker to move their reasoning to a separate answer and let the question only have the puzzle part.

Comment: I don't think that formatting should be an issue here. New users are unaware of the formatting used here and that's why there is a privilege given to us so that we can edit a post.

Comment: @manshu That's what I think as well.